# Prolog program to return atoms in a proposition formula

Tags: prolog

I am a newbie to prolog and am trying to write a program which returns the `atoms` in a well formed propositional formula. For instance the query `ats(and(q, imp(or(p, q), neg(p))), As).` should return `[p,q]` for `As`. Below is my code which returns the formula as `As`. I dont know what to do to split the `single F` in `ats` in the `F1` and `F2` in `wff` so `wff/2` never gets called. Please I need help to proceed from here. Thanks.

**CODE**

```
logical_atom( A ) :-
       atom( A ),     
       atom_codes( A, [AH|_] ),
       AH >= 97,
       AH =< 122.

wff(A):- ground(A),
         logical_atom(A).

wff(neg(A)) :- ground(A),wff(A).

wff(or(F1,F2)) :-
    wff(F1),
    wff(F2).
wff(and(F1,F2)) :-
    wff(F1),
    wff(F2).

wff(imp(F1,F2)) :-
    wff(F1),
    wff(F2).
ats(F, As):- wff(F), setof(F, logical_atom(F), As).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. It extracts the unique set of atoms found in any arbitrary prolog term.

I'll leave it up to you, though, to determine what constitutes a "*well formed propositional formula*", as you put it in your problem statement (You might want to take a look at DCG's for parsing and validation).

The bulk of the work is done by this "worker predicate". It simply extracts, one at a time via backtracking, any atoms found in the parse tree and discards anything else:

```
expression_atom( [T|_] , T ) :-  % Case #1: head of list is an ordinary atom
  atom(T) ,                      % - verify that the head of the list is an atom.
  T \= []                        % - and not an empty list
  .                              % 
expression_atom( [T|_] , A ) :-  % Case #2: head of listl is a compound term
  compound(T) ,                  % - verify that the head of the list is a compound term
  T =.. [_|Ts] ,                 % - decompose it, discarding the functor and keeping the arguments
  expression_atom(Ts,A)          % - recurse down on the term's arguments
  .                              %
expression_atom( [_|Ts] , A ) :- % Finally, on backtracking,
  expression_atom(Ts,A)          % - we simply discard the head and recurse down on the tail
  .                              %
```

Then, at the top level, we have this simple predicate that accepts any [compound] prolog term and extracts the unique set of atoms found within by the worker predicate via `setof/3`:

```
expression_atoms( T , As ) :-       % To get the set of unique atoms in an arbitrary term,
  compound(T) ,                     % - ensure that's its a compound term,
  T =.. [_|Ts] ,                    % - decompose it, discarding the functor and keeping the arguments
  setof(A,expression_atom(Ts,A),As) % - invoke the worker predicate via setof/3
  .                                 % Easy!
```

Answer (score 4):

First, consider using a cleaner representation: Currently, you cannot distinguish atoms by a common functor. So, wrap them for example in `a(Atom)`.

Second, use a DCG to describe the relation between a well-formed formula and the list of its atoms, like in:

```
wff_atoms(a(A))       --> [A].
wff_atoms(neg(F))     --> wff_atoms(F).
wff_atoms(or(F1,F2))  --> wff_atoms(F1), wff_atoms(F2).
wff_atoms(and(F1,F2)) --> wff_atoms(F1), wff_atoms(F2).
wff_atoms(imp(F1,F2)) --> wff_atoms(F1), wff_atoms(F2).
```

Example query and its result:

```
?- phrase(wff_atoms(and(a(q), imp(or(a(p), a(q)), neg(a(p))))), As).
As = [q, p, q, p].
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need the query such as ? wff(and(q, imp(or(p, q), neg(p))), As). to give me a unique list of atoms directly. I have already define my atom in a code snippet above.

Comment: You can simply add it as a predicate: `wff(F, As) :- phrase(wff_atoms(F), As0), sort(As0, As).`

Comment: Thanks again but please understand am a newbie, I dont really understand prolog procedures and I really want to keep my logical_atom predicate and my definition of a well formed propositional formula. I just want to be able to know when F becomes F1 and F2 from ats to WFF and how to populate the set of atoms. I hope I dont sound confusing.

Comment: Especially as a newbie, aim for clean representations: They let you distinguish different entitites already by their functors, so that you can use pattern matching, and your predicates work naturally in all directions, even when their arguments are variables. For example, the code you originally posted does not find a single solution for the query `?- wff(A).`, although there are infinitely many atoms it could choose from to give solutions! If you are given an unclean representation, first convert it to a clean one! Write `wff_clean/2`, then use `wff_atoms//1` on the clean representation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this problem using the "univ" operator `=../2` and explicit recursion. Note that this solution will not generate and is not "logically correct" in that it will not process a structure with holes generously, so it will produce different results if conditions are reordered. Please see @mat's comments below.

I'm using cuts instead of if statements for personal aesthetics; you would certainly find better performance with a large explicit conditional tree. I'm not sure you'd want a predicate such as this to generate in the first place.

Univ is handy because it lets you treat Prolog terms similarly to how you would treat a complex s-expression in Lisp: it converts terms to lists of atoms. This lets you traverse Prolog terms as lists, which is handy if you aren't sure exactly what you'll be processing. It saves me from having to look for your boolean operators explicitly.

```
atoms_of_prop(Prop, Atoms) :-
    % discard the head of the term ('and', 'imp', etc.)
    Prop =.. [_|PropItems],

    collect_atoms(PropItems, AtomsUnsorted),

    % sorting makes the list unique in Prolog
    sort(AtomsUnsorted, Atoms).
```

The helper predicate `collect_atoms/2` processes lists of terms (univ only dismantles the outermost layer) and is mutually recursive with `atoms_of_prop/2` when it finds terms. If it finds atoms, it just adds them to the result.

```
% base case
collect_atoms([], []).

% handle atoms
collect_atoms([A|Ps], [A|Rest]) :-
    % you could replace the next test with logical_atom/1
    atom(A), !,
    collect_atoms(Ps, Rest).

% handle terms
collect_atoms([P|Ps], Rest) :-
    compound(P), !,                % compound/1 tests for terms
    atoms_of_prop(P, PAtoms),
    collect_atoms(Ps, PsAtoms),
    append(PAtoms, PsAtoms, Rest).

% ignore everything else
collect_atoms([_|Ps], Rest) :- atoms_of_prop(Ps, Rest).
```

This works for your example as-is:

```
?- atoms_of_prop(ats(and(q, imp(or(p, q), neg(p))), As), Atoms).
Atoms = [p, q].
```

Comment: Unfortunately this yields wrong results: Consider for example `?- atoms_of_prop(and(X,a), Ls), X = b, Ls = [a,b].`, which fails. However, when you simply exchange the first two goals by commutativity of conjunction, it succeeds.

Comment: @mat I appreciate your pointing out the shortcoming, but it's up to the OP to decide whether it is wrong. It looks to me like they're doing their own variable substitution process so this may be the result of a parse tree, which is unlikely to contain holes.

Comment: OP, despite being a Prolog newbie, will very likely also know that conjunction is supposed to be a commutative predicate.

Comment: @mat Prolog newbies often have a better appreciation of the fact that programs are executed on machines instead of hypothetically by logicians. I trust that even if you know Prolog better than me and I better than the OP, the OP knows their problem better than either of us and would prefer to see several approaches, weigh the tradeoffs and make an informed decision, rather than be told solution one is wrong because edge cases that may not pertain to their problem domain at all.

Comment: @mat I have edited the answer to make your comments explicit in the up-front fine print. If you see an obvious solution (perhaps `atom(X) ; var(X)` if not too confining or too broad) or if you dislike my fine print, please let me know and I will update the answer.