# How to get list of atom variables from a term in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How to get list of atom variables from a term

For example-

```
Term = (h-5)* (h-5)+ (k- -2)* (k- -2)- (h-3)* (h-3)- (k-4)* (k-4)=0,
get_variables(Term, Var_list).
```

For above term, the answer would be `Var_list = [h,k].`

Answer (score 3):

The following code runs with both SICStus Prolog 4.5.0 and SWI-Prolog 8.0.0.

It is based on [`library(terms)`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dterms.html) and [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/772868):

```
:- use_module(library(terms)).

atoms_in(As, T) :-
   (  \+ acyclic_term(T)
   -> throw(error(type_error(acyclic_term, T), _))
   ;  iwhen(ground(T), setof(A, (sub_term(A,T),atom(A)), As))
   -> true
   ;  As = []
   ).
```

Using SWI-Prolog 8.0.0:

```
?- atoms_in(Xs, (h-5)*(h-5)+(k- -2)*(k- -2)-(h-3)*(h-3)-(k-4)*(k-4)=0).
Xs = [h, k].

?- atoms_in(Xs, f(g(a,b),h(c,d))).
Xs = [a, b, c, d].

?- atoms_in(Xs, f(g(1,2),3)).
Xs = [].

?- atoms_in(Xs, 1).
Xs = [].
```

Note how invalid uses are caught and reported:

```
?- atoms_in(_, _).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- atoms_in(_, f(_)).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- Term = f(a,Term), atoms_in(_, Term).
ERROR: Type error: `acyclic_term' expected, found `@(S_1,[S_1=f(a,S_1)])' (a cyclic)
```

Comment: [library(terms)](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dterms.html#lib_002dterms) is also available in recent versions of SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Here is [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557317/975097) to this problem on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndersonGreen. Yes, the library *is* present. I didn't find it in the manual, so I skipped SWI. Will update my answer accordingly... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work (a nice problem by the way):

```
variables(T,V):-
    variables(T,[],V1),
    sort(V1,V).

variables(T,Acc,[T|V]):-
    var(T), !,
    variables(Acc,[],V).
variables([],[],[]).
variables([],Acc,V):-
    variables(Acc,[],V).
variables([H|T],Acc,V):-
    append(T,Acc,NewAcc),
    variables(H,NewAcc,V).
variables(T,Acc,V):-
    atom(T),
    variables(Acc,[],V).
variables(T,Acc,V):-
    T=.. [_F|AL],
    variables(AL,Acc,V).
```

Your query would be

```
?- variables((H-5)* (H-5)+ (K- -2)* (K- -2)- (H-3)* (H-3)- (K-4)* (K-4)=0,VL).
```

Comment: Your query finds the right solution, but then it loops.

Comment: There is a built-in for your (interpretation of OP's) predicate: `term_variables/2`.

Comment: @false But this is a different problem, since this question is about generating lists of atoms instead of variables.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: My comment is about JoanC's interpretation, only.